# How to add Native Full Screen Video Ads in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, ads, facebook-ads-api, native-ads

I'm trying to make an app where I want full screen video ads to display but not like the typical ones with white background and a video holder in between, I want to make something like the ads that pop up in between Youtube Shorts that are full screen, I found Facebook Native Ads but they too have that white background with ad holder in between, Is there any other Ad Network that I can use if it's not possible with Facebook Ad Network? I've just tried Facebook Native Ads as of now

Comment: refer to attached link, you can integrate google admob with flutter.https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter/

Comment: Actually what I'm tryna do is against Google Admobs policy but not Facebook Ads, Is there any other Ad Network that I can use?